# kvaser_interface need library: libcanlib.so.1. Should I install linuxcan lib or now?

Tags: ros, can-bus

It seems that I'm facing a delemma. I need to run kvaser_interface ROS1 (noetic, 1.15.14) node. I'm using this repo: https://github.com/astuff/kvaser_interface

I follow this link to install kvaser CAN/USB driver on my ubuntu 20.04.4. If I don't install CANlib or linuxcan, I can have my CAN network working (can0 is listed, candump and cansend works). But kvaser_interface needs a library from linuxcan, hence gives me error:

```
... kvaser_can_bridge: error while loading shared libraries: libcanlib.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Apparently kvaser_interface node requires CANlib. So I installed linuxcan and CANlib using:

```
sudo make install
```

kvaser_interface runs without a problem. But can0 isn't working anymore.

```
ip link
```

doesn't show can0. Also

```
sudo ip link set can0 type can bitrate 500000
```

gives

```
Cannot find device "can0"
```

This is because linuxcan blacklists socketCAN. It seems that I'm facing a delimma. Also I'm not clear what role CANlib is playing here. Any suggests will help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this yet, but you can go into the
`/etc/modprobe.d/kvaser.conf`
and sudo edit the file to delete the blacklisted modules:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/110341/how-to-blacklist-kernel-modules

Comment: ultimately I had to just completely get rid of canLib